# wpColorPicker - problem with implementation to post meta

Tags: posts, post-meta

I need your help as I am stuck and Google does not return anything, so I must be doing something obiusly wrong here, I just don't know what.

Basically, I need color input in one of my custom post types meta and I am trying to use a new WordPress 3.5 colorpicker for that. I could simply find another script and use it, but if it's already bundled with WP, that's what I should use.

So anyway, this is what I have done:

I have this input field in custom metabox:

```
<input name="mv_cr_section_color" type="text" id="mv_cr_section_color" value="<?php echo $sections_color; ?>" data-default-color="#ffffff">
```

I have this piece for enqueueing the script needed:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
```

and finally I have this custom js:

```
jQuery('#mv_cr_section_color').wpColorPicker();
```

wrapped in .ready()

Result is this:
Input field gets hidden (it gets display: none inline urle applied to it), if I uncheck that (using Google Chrome), when I click the field nothing happens (:focus should trigger colorpicker). If I then unhide colorpicker (it is spawned, I see it in source) I can use it and it functions normally, default color also works well but I just can't find the reason why field gets hidden and why it does not open colorpicker on focus.

Anyone have any idea, I am really ... about this :)

Thanks

EDIT: Just the note, no error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following and it works:

```
function wpse_80236_Colorpicker(){ 
    // you forgot this probably it's the bundled CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');
    //
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_80236_Colorpicker');
```

Then your input:

```
<input name="mv_cr_section_color" type="text" id="mv_cr_section_color" value="#ffffff" data-default-color="#ffffff">
```

Then the following js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mv_cr_section_color').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Comment: I have to because in that variable I hold the color saved in post_meta, how else would I remeber user's choice?

I did check out that website and also a few other exact tutorials, also a sample plugin maed but nothing helped me realize where I have mistaken.

Comment: The suggestion was to debug it, to see if it works or not.

Comment: Ok, just tested without the php part (clean html input field) and still the same thing happens.

Comment: OK I think I know what's wrong gimme 1 min

Comment: did you try to also `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );`

Comment: OMG yuo are right, that's the missing piece, thnak you so much for this help, I was going nuts :) 

Thanks thanks thanks!